# Error of calculated X from measured Y (instrument calibration with linear regression)

Tags: regression

I have what I am pretty sure is a simple problem that I can't get a hold on and could use some help!

I am sampling air and using a gas chromatograph (GC) quantify my results. I want to calculate a total combined error for my final number, but I am stuck on the standard error of the mass that I get back from my GC's calibration's linear regression.

Here's the whole story: I have an instrument that I have calibrated with known concentrations, x, to get instrument responses, y. I perform a linear regression to get an equation, y = mx + b. I take a sample for a measured time at a measured flow rate to get my total volume of air collected. This number has simple errors associated with them that I have not problem combining to get my volume and associated error. I then run the sample on my calibrated GC, get an instrument response, y, then use the equation for the line I got from my linear regression to calculate the mass in the sample, x = (y-b)/m.

So how do I calculate the error associated with that calculated x! The closest I have come is the equation at the bottom of the table in this link:

http://chemlab.truman.edu/DataAnalysis/Propagation%20of%20Error/PropagationofError.htm

When I use that, I get reasonable numbers, I was just hoping for a better reference to use. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: EdM has already given a good answer. If you wish to research further, it may help to know this problem is often solved with "inverse regression."  Google ["inverse regression" calibration](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22inverse+regression%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22inverse+regression%22+calibration) for links to good resources.

Answer (score 1):

This is, as you suspect, a standard problem in analytical chemistry. The equation you linked to is Equation 5.25 in this [free Analytical Chemistry textbook](http://acad.depauw.edu/harvey_web/eText%20Project/pdf%20file/AnalChem2.0.pdf) ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20150907100228/http://acad.depauw.edu/harvey_web/eText%20Project/pdf%20file/AnalChem2.0.pdf)), for the case where the residual errors in the measurements of $y$ are independent of the value of $y$, and the text provides references to its derivation. The formula takes into account the error in the measurement of $y$ and the errors arising from the regression that provided the calibration curve.

Importantly, Chapter 5 of that texbook continues with ways to evaluate the validity of the calibration scheme. Make sure that you move on from simply plugging numbers into a formula, and learn how to evaluate when the formula is applicable and what to do when it isn't.